# How to vertically center a <span> inside a div?

Tags: html, css, center

The code:

```
<div 
  id="theMainDiv"
  style="
    border:solid 1px gray;
    cursor:text;
    width:400px;
    padding:0px;"
>
  <span 
    id="tag1_outer" 
    style="
      background:#e2e6f0;
      padding-right:4px;
      padding-left:4px;
      border:solid 1px #9daccc;
      font:normal 11px arial;
      color:#3c3c3c"
  >as</span>
</div>
```

As it renders now, the span is align the bottom-left corner of the div.

Comment: Solution without lineheight and with flex is:

  id="theMainDiv"
  style="
    border:solid 1px gray;
    cursor:text;
    width:400px;
    padding:0px;
    display:flex;
    align-content: middle;"

Answer (score 217, accepted):

See my article on [understanding vertical alignment](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html). There are multiple techniques to accomplish what you want at the end of the discussion.

*(Super-short summary: either set the line-height of the child equal to the height of the container, or set positioning on the container and absolutely position the child at `top:50%` with `margin-top:-YYYpx`, YYY being half the known height of the child.)*

Comment: @Blender Heh, though therein references a third option: `display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle` (along with a `display:table-row` parent). :) But no, you can be sure that I would [never advocate using HTML table elements for layout](http://phrogz.net/CSS/WhyTablesAreBadForLayout.html).

Comment: what happens if you padding-top??? a fixed no based on height of the parent. i think your solution works even if the height is dynamic right.

Comment: So if you want to do this without a fixed height, there's no way to do it?

Comment: @Kyralessa No, if you don't have a fixed height for the content there exist a couple techniques not yet listed in my page. For example, see: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: @Phrogz - you should add the last option in http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/ to your answer. It's so clean and ie8+!

Comment: @StevenLu Thanks for the motivation. 5 years ago I had not the experience with SO that I have now, and I too would downvote my answer as it is only a link to an external site. I will find time to put the various code answers into my answer. Hopefully "soon".

Comment: Yep, there are a lot of helpful articles out there by now that show many ways to get this job done. However, It's really a shame how complex every one of these approaches is. Flexbox offers a glimmer of hope, but is also incredibly complex.

Comment: "Setting the line-height equal to that of container.." doesn't seem to work when the text on line is using different font sizes. e.g. In method 2 example in your article, I changed the text "is" to <span style="font-size:72px;">is</span> and text was no longer appearing at center. This was exactly the case for which I was looking for a way to center and I chanced upon this question.

Comment: What if `YYY` is unknown??

Answer (score 210):

At your parent DIV add

```
display:table;
```

and at your child element add

```
 display:table-cell;
 vertical-align:middle;
```

Comment: This works, but is there an easy way to horizontally center the child element in the parent as well?  Since the child's display isn't an inline-block anymore, the parent's "text-align: center;" css no longer works.

Answer (score 75):

**Quick answer for single line span**

Make the child (in this case a span) the same `line-height` as the parent `<div>`'s height

```
<div class="parent">
  <span class="child">Yes mom, I did my homework lol</span>
</div>
```

You should then add the CSS rules

```
.parent { height: 20px; }
.child { line-height: 20px; vertical-align: middle; }
```

---

Or you can target it with a child selector

```
.parent { height: 20px; }
.parent > span { line-height: 20px; vertical-align: middle; }
```

**Background on my own use of this**

I ran into this similar issue where I needed to vertically center items in a mobile menu. I made the div and spans inside the same line height. Note that this is for a meteor project and therefore not using inline css ;)

**HTML**

```
<div class="international">        
  <span class="intlFlag">
    {{flag}}        
  </span>

  <span class="intlCurrent">
    {{country}}
  </span>

  <span class="intlButton">
    <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
  </span> 
</div>
```

**CSS** (option for multiple spans in a div)

```
.international {
  height: 42px;
}

.international > span {
  line-height: 42px;
}
```

In this case if I just had one span I could have added the CSS rule directly to that span.

**CSS** (option for one specific span)

```
.intlFlag { line-height: 42px; }
```

Here is how it displayed for me

[image]

Comment: Upvote for high-quality child div example text.

Comment: this only works if the text does not go over multiple lines

Comment: @Guillaume yeah it's literally mentioned in the opening sentence.

Answer (score 42):

[As in a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617337/vertical-centering-a-block-a-in-ie7/8796289#8796289), use `display: inline-block` with a placeholder element to vertically center the span inside of a block element:

```css
html, body, #container, #placeholder { height: 100%; }

#content, #placeholder { display:inline-block; vertical-align: middle; }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <span id="content">
        Content
      </span>
      <span id="placeholder"></span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Vertical alignment is only applied to [inline elements or table cells](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height), so use it along with `display:inline-block` or `display:table-cell` with a `display:table` parent when vertically centering block elements.

**References:**

[CSS Horizontal and Vertical Centering](http://www.brunildo.org/test/img_center.html)

Comment: The solution works as long as #content is not wrapped

Answer (score 1):

To the parent div add a height say 50px. In the child span, add the line-height: 50px; 
Now the text in the span will be vertically center. This worked for me.