# CSS and nested tables TD width vertical align on grid

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

I am trying to align a table data columns to have the same width even if they are nested ... so I thought a fixed width will solve it in CSS
I apply to every TABLE TR TD:nthclild(X) a different width..and yes it applies in firebug all that..but...

For some reason... it doesn't show like desired...(see screenshot), all is vertically unaligned:

[image]

I tried different width.. and I'm simply going mad with this because I don't know what to do with it...

I will attach the full zip file to have all the css as I have it...
I can use CSS3 and Jquery and the lastest browsers ... don't care about IE and stuff

Does anyone know how to do this? I'm out of ideeas

Here's the whole page with css,
[(zip link here)](http://usamicasa.com/Archive.zip)

Comment: Have you tried setting a fixed width on all cells in a row except for one?

Comment: now that you mentioned it.. it did, but no effect

Comment: Looks like the rows with a single td with colspan gets a width of 30px due to nth child rule. You should try to avoid that. In addition you should make sure that any of the cells doesn't get wider than set width (due to lack of white space).

Comment: well there isn't any way to prevent to be bigger than the actual with.. other than cutting the actual text with overflow
And tried to prevent that the colspan don't get a width...
Still it doesn't do anything :( ... The wierdest thing ..

Comment: Ok, I have a lead... 1st nested has 22 colspan and the 2nd nested has 23 colspan.. so the nthchild .. arrent's the same then...
What I don't understand is why they have 1 more column..

Comment: Yea, I believe that is the issue. If you can hide one of the cells with `display:none` I believe it could work. Plus the inner tables get double borders which misalign the cells a bit as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `div` with `display:inline-block` to enforce the vertical alignment as in these unrelated questions:

- [How to vertically center a <span> inside a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357315/how-to-vertically-center-a-span-inside-a-div/11161968#11161968)
- [How to stretch a fixed number of horizontal navigation items evenly and fully across a specified container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060923/how-to-stretch-html-css-horizontal-navigation-items-evenly-and-fully-across-a/14187847#14187847)