# CSS vertical alignment and baseline position

Tags: vertical-alignment, html, css, baseline

I am new to CSS and recently reading the specification and having some problems in understanding the vertical-align property.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black;">
<span style="border: 1px solid red; padding-left: 1px; line-height: 30px;"></span>
<span style="border: 1px solid red; padding-left: 1px;"></span>
<span style="border: 1px solid red; padding-left: 1px; line-height: 40px;"></span>
</div>

<div style="border: 1px solid black;">
<span style="border: 1px solid red; padding-left: 1px; line-height: 30px;"></span>
<span style="border: 1px solid red; padding-left: 1px;"></span>
<span style="border: 1px solid red; padding-left: 1px; line-height: 40px; vertical-align: top"></span>
</div>

<div style="border: 1px solid black;">
<span style="border: 1px solid red; padding-left: 1px; line-height: 30px; vertical-align: bottom"></span>
<span style="border: 1px solid red; padding-left: 1px;"></span>
<span style="border: 1px solid red; padding-left: 1px; line-height: 40px; vertical-align: top"></span>
</div>
```

Above code creates 3 div, each of them contains 3 empty inline boxes (spans):

1. In the 1st div, everything seems fine. All the 3 spans are aligned to the baseline of the line box.
2. In the 2nd div, after I set the `vertical-align` property to `top` for the 3rd span, the first two spans are moved up. And I get lost from here, I don't understand why they will be moved up, according to what rule.
3. The 3rd div is even more wired to me. I set the `vertical-align` property to `bottom` for the 1st span, and it causes the 2nd span to move **slightly lower** than the 3rd span (this will be noticed when zoom in enough).

The thing I can find in the specification says below, but what exactly are the **`multiple solutions`**? Could anyone shed more light on this?

`In case they are aligned 'top' or 'bottom', they must be aligned so as to minimize the line box height. If such boxes are tall enough, there are multiple solutions and CSS 2.1 does not define the position of the line box's baseline.`

I've also created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kUC72/). Please run it in Firefox or Chrome if you are interested.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357315/how-to-vertically-center-a-span-inside-a-div

Comment: Note that the fiddle's third example is different in IE (11) from Chrome (31) and Firefox (25 & 26).

Answer (score 9):

`vertical-align` is mostly used for `inline` element for example `img` tag, which is commonly set to `vertical-align: middle;` inorder to align correctly within the text.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SNFfs/) (Without the use of `vertical-align`)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/SNFfs/1/) (Using `vertical-align`)

Ok, so that was a general idea of how `vertical-align` works with a value of `middle`.

So, first lets see what are the valid values for [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property.

[image]
<sup>Credits : [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org)</sup>

Now, lets solve your doubt step by step..

In the first example, everything's fine according to you but the answer is no, you are applying `line-height` to the `span` which varies, but the fact is `line-height` is actually not applied as the way you think...

[Line height is actually not getting applied](http://jsfiddle.net/awpZm/)

[Make it `inline-block` and it will be applied](http://jsfiddle.net/awpZm/1/)

You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829393/why-the-spans-line-height-is-useless) answer for more information, that why using `line-height` on `span` is useless.

---

Moving on to your second doubt, you are having `line-height` on first `span`, second `span` but not the third `span` so what's happening here? As `span` is `inline` with the text and anyways `line-height` won't play the role there as I previously explained, they are happily aligned vertically with the text, whereas when you use `vertical-align: top;`, it doesn't move the other two boxes above that, instead it aligns to the *top of the text*.

[See how the `vertical-align: top;` aligns at the top of the text](http://jsfiddle.net/awpZm/2/)

---

Coming to the last example of yours, in here, first `span` element is aligned to the very `bottom` as expected, well its correct, moving on to second, you said it's slightly in the *lower* than the third, because it is not aligned at all, `line-height` is what it makes that element `align` vertically `center` and last, moves a bit to the `top`, which is infact aligned to the `top`.

[Lets make them `inline-block` and see how they actually behave..](http://jsfiddle.net/awpZm/3/)

So I hope you got the difference between all the three examples, but its necessary for you to understand the `line-height` property and `inline-block` property as well, also don't forget to refer the answer I shared.

Comment: Hi, @Mr. Alien, I still think the `line-height` property will be applied to `inline` elements. According to the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height), when calculating the height of line box, `1.The height of each inline-level box in the line box is calculated. For replaced elements, inline-block elements, and inline-table elements, this is the height of their margin box; for inline boxes, this is their 'line-height'`

Comment: What I am assuming is that setting the `vertical-align` property in the inline boxes to `top/down` will actually change the baseline position of the line box. And due to the baseline is moved up or down, the other boxes will be affected somehow. But I am not sure whether I am heading to the right direction...

Comment: @YuanLi baseline doesn't move, the boxes touch the baseline or the top, depends on what you set

Comment: I did read your answer and links as well as the one given by Dilish, and I still insist, at least for the time being :) Might be I need sometime to digest