# vertical-align: why it does not work for me?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

Here is html:

```
<div style="height: 100px">
    <span style="vertical-align:top;">top</span>
    <span style="vertical-align:bottom;">bottom</span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CaS5r/1/

Why `vertical-align` property does not work in this example? Do I use it incorrectly?

Comment: Possibly similar query here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357315/how-to-vertically-center-a-span-inside-a-div

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/

Comment: thats why to use vertical align [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/zekuk/1/edit)

Comment: this is also a great explanation http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/

Comment: @aldanux: so vertical-align applies only with respect to adjacent elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure what you want to achieve.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CaS5r/4/

It does work, but it only aligns to it's siblings.

#### some debugging

```
span {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
div {
    background: yellow;
    height: 100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div >
    <span style="vertical-align:top;">top</span>
    <span style="vertical-align:middle;">middle</span>
    <span style="vertical-align:baseline;">baseline</span>
    <span style="vertical-align:bottom;">bottom</span>
</div>
```

### UPDATE

you can see it better if the font is bigger (e.g. 50px)  http://jsfiddle.net/CaS5r/5/

### UPDATE

You probably want to use `display: table;`

http://jsfiddle.net/CaS5r/7/

Then it does what you expect

Comment: I am trying to get some understanding about vertical-align. I didn't know it applies only with respect to its siblings.

Comment: @clime see the last fiddle in my updated answer: I guess that is what you want

Comment: I wanted to get just the understanding, which I have got. but thanks for updates.