# How to vertical-center text inside this span

Tags: html, css

I have a piece of code for a website that I'm writing, that I can't figure out.

```css
.program_category_description {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  max-width:1300px;
}
.program_category_description .description {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 2% 1% 2% 1%;
}
.program_category_description .title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.program_category_description .more_info {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #CE6D2B;
}
.program_category_description .more_info a {
  color: white !important;
}
.more_info_btn {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  -o-transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
  transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
}
.more_info_btn:hover {
  background-color: #b96226;
}
.more_info_btn:active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="article_body_section program_category_description">
  <div class="description">
    <div class="title">Short Term Programs</div>
    <div class="description_description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis euismod lacus vitae dui fermentum, quis lacinia risus viverra. Nulla aliquam leo quis velit dictum viverra. Duis vehicula pharetra imperdiet. Duis eleifend orci eget ultrices convallis.
      Nulla nec aliqu.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="more_info"><a href="#"><span class="more_info_btn">More Info</span></a>
  </div>

</div>
```

The reasoning for the span is so that the whole orange block is a clickable link. The problem is that I want the "more info" text to be centered within the block at all times. I don't want to give it specific pixel properties as I want it to stretch or get bigger when resized. The only restriction is a max-width of 1300px.

I have already tried vertical align, or adding a percentage based padding, but none work. As you can probably tell, I am not very experienced in this and learning by day, so if you see other things worth pointing out in the code, or other solutions, please do.

Comment: For me the text is perfectly aligned to the center? vertical and horizontal?

Comment: Is aligned to the center, vertically and horizontally. What's the problem?

Comment: @Aaron The "more info" part is definitely not aligned to the center, top-wise. I think vertically aligned is the name? I can make a screenshot if you want.

Comment: Click on **Run code snippet** you will see it is vertically aligned?

Comment: Ahhh, i'm using firefox... it's not in chrome :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to vertically center a <span> inside a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357315/how-to-vertically-center-a-span-inside-a-div)

Comment: In firefox runs ok. Chrome is making "puñetas" with his bugs.

Comment: @Aaron, this is how I view it. http://i.imgur.com/fwnPWCB.png

Comment: Ah-ah, so it's chrome, I see. Would there be a workaround?

Comment: @Gerardo a cross-browser solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32475947/5035890

Comment: this question asker is violating the rule of downvoting so please suggest him about the downvoting rule of SO

Comment: @Amitsingh I am not downvoting any answer. All of the downvotes are being given by other users. Also, I believe that I cannot downvote due to being a new account. Not sure if that is what you meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` alongside with `align-items: center`:

```css
.program_category_description {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  max-width: 1300px;
}
.program_category_description .description {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 2% 1% 2% 1%;
}
.program_category_description .title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.program_category_description .more_info {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #CE6D2B;
}
.program_category_description .more_info a {
  color: white !important;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: blink;
}
.more_info_btn {
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  -o-transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
  transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.more_info_btn:hover {
  background-color: #b96226;
}
.more_info_btn:active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="article_body_section program_category_description">
  <div class="description">
    <div class="title">Short Term Programs</div>
    <div class="description_description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis euismod lacus vitae dui fermentum, quis lacinia risus viverra. Nulla aliquam leo quis velit dictum viverra. Duis vehicula pharetra imperdiet. Duis eleifend orci eget ultrices convallis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis euismod lacus vitae dui fermentum, quis lacinia risus viverra. Nulla aliquam leo quis velit dictum viverra. Duis vehicula pharetra imperdiet. Duis eleifend orci eget ultrices convallis.
      Nulla nec aliqu.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="more_info"><a href="#"><span class="more_info_btn">More Info</span></a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Second example with very long text:

```css
.program_category_description {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  max-width: 1300px;
}
.program_category_description .description {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 2% 1% 2% 1%;
}
.program_category_description .title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.program_category_description .more_info {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #CE6D2B;
}
.program_category_description .more_info a {
  color: white !important;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: blink;
}
.more_info_btn {
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  -o-transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
  transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.more_info_btn:hover {
  background-color: #b96226;
}
.more_info_btn:active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="article_body_section program_category_description">
  <div class="description">
    <div class="title">Short Term Programs</div>
    <div class="description_description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis euismod lacus vitae dui fermentum, quis lacinia risus viverra. Nulla aliquam leo quis velit dictum viverra. Duis vehicula pharetra imperdiet. Duis eleifend orci eget ultrices convallis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis euismod lacus vitae dui fermentum, quis lacinia risus viverra. Nulla aliquam leo quis velit dictum viverra. Duis vehicula pharetra imperdiet. Duis eleifend orci eget ultrices convallis. Nulla nec aliqu. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis euismod lacus vitae dui fermentum, quis lacinia risus viverra. Nulla aliquam leo quis velit dictum viverra. Duis vehicula pharetra imperdiet. Duis eleifend orci eget ultrices convallis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis euismod lacus vitae dui fermentum, quis lacinia risus viverra. Nulla aliquam leo quis velit dictum viverra. Duis vehicula pharetra imperdiet. Duis eleifend orci eget ultrices convallis. Nulla nec aliqu.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="more_info"><a href="#"><span class="more_info_btn">More Info</span></a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hello Alex, as you can see when you run it, that breaks the whole orange box being a link. Is there a way around it? Thank you for the time.

Comment: at least for me, in the updated code, the box isn't a link still. Only the section that contains the text up to the sides of the box, but not above or under.

Comment: so about our answer we also suggested you the same answer

Comment: I retract, didn't see how you did it. Unfortunately setting it at a fixed line heigth doesn't work, as there are different boxes like this, and when you expand/contract them, there are more lines of text, and the more info doesn't adjust to the new heigth of the box.

Comment: @Gerardo check it I think is ok now.

Comment: Yes! I will be looking into what changes you did to analyze and learn from it. Thank you! On a side note, it seems that someone dedicated themselves to downvote every post of this question, making it look like it was myself.

Comment: Glad that I helped you. No it can't be you because you need some reputation before you can down vote.

Answer (score 1):

Just add your `a` tag instead your div:
(This is a cross-browser solution. It works in firefox, chrome and IE)

```css
.program_category_description {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  max-width:1300px;
}
.program_category_description .description {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 2% 1% 2% 1%;
}
.program_category_description .title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.program_category_description .more_info {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #CE6D2B;
}
.program_category_description .more_info a {
  color: white !important;
}
.more_info_btn {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  -o-transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
  transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
}
.more_info:hover {
  background-color: #b96226;
}
.more_info:active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="article_body_section program_category_description">
  <div class="description">
    <div class="title">Short Term Programs</div>
    <div class="description_description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis euismod lacus vitae dui fermentum, quis lacinia risus viverra. Nulla aliquam leo quis velit dictum viverra. Duis vehicula pharetra imperdiet. Duis eleifend orci eget ultrices convallis.
      Nulla nec aliqu.</div>
  </div>
  <a class="more_info" href="#"><span class="more_info_btn">More Info</span></a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: And take the height:100% off of `.more_info_btn`

Answer (score 0):

I think this might solve your problem..

You just have to change `display:inline-block` into `display:table-cell` in the `.more_info_btn`

and make `div` an `a` tag so that the whole box will be `link`

Answer (score 0):

Ammit Singh was correct

if you give your  a class of block

```
 <div class="more_info"><a href="#" class="block"><span class="more_info_btn">More Info</span></a>
```

Then create the .block class in css

```
.block{display:block;}
```

problem is solved

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the display inline-block from the `.more_info_btn` :)

```css
.program_category_description {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  max-width:1300px;
}
.program_category_description .description {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 2% 1% 2% 1%;
}
.program_category_description .title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.program_category_description .more_info {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #CE6D2B;
}
.program_category_description .more_info a {
  color: white !important;
}
.more_info_btn {
  font-size: 20px;
 /* display: inline-block;*/
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  -o-transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
  transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
}
.more_info_btn:hover {
  background-color: #b96226;
}
.more_info_btn:active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="article_body_section program_category_description">
  <div class="description">
    <div class="title">Short Term Programs</div>
    <div class="description_description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis euismod lacus vitae dui fermentum, quis lacinia risus viverra. Nulla aliquam leo quis velit dictum viverra. Duis vehicula pharetra imperdiet. Duis eleifend orci eget ultrices convallis.
      Nulla nec aliqu.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="more_info"><a href="#"><span class="more_info_btn">More Info</span></a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: lol, love the -1 with no comment? removing the display property does align it vertically?

Answer (score -1):

```css
.program_category_description {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  max-width:1300px;
}
.program_category_description .description {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 2% 1% 2% 1%;
}
.program_category_description .title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.program_category_description .more_info {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #CE6D2B;
}
.program_category_description .more_info a {
  color: white !important;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}
.more_info_btn {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: table-call;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  -o-transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
  transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
}
.more_info_btn:hover {
  background-color: #b96226;
}
.more_info_btn:active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="article_body_section program_category_description">
  <div class="description">
    <div class="title">Short Term Programs</div>
    <div class="description_description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis euismod lacus vitae dui fermentum, quis lacinia risus viverra. Nulla aliquam leo quis velit dictum viverra. Duis vehicula pharetra imperdiet. Duis eleifend orci eget ultrices convallis.
      Nulla nec aliqu.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="more_info"><a href="#"><span class="more_info_btn">More Info</span></a>
  </div>

</div>
```